# PDF viewer with cuts for big files

Tags: debian, pdf, image-viewer

My file has 1Mx1M points and I cannot open it with Evince. 
There must be something else for the task.

OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: try `mupdf` which is not based on libpoppler. Or convert the pdf into png, and view with `vips` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIPS_(software)

Comment: I generate data from R. So maybe directly dfrom there to some viewer.

Comment: You can open pdf files with [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was finally to improve the LaTeX quality, by removing all errors, and/or warnings. 
It decreased the size of the file by 60-80%. 
The other options proposed here are not sufficient for the task. 
Open still remains the effect of the file size on the reading speed in the pdf viewer.

Evince is already 64-bit, and mature. 
So I could not find anything to improve in the viewer itself. 
Mostly on the file side, by LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

Viewing those files is best done by first extracting the images using `pdfimages your_file.pdf` and then use a normal image viewer on the resulting image(s).

PDF is one of the worst programs to store image files in. If you need to have multiple images in a file, a TIFF file with (multiple) tiled images can handle larges images like yours much better, and a viewer doesn't have to get the whole image in memore before displaying, only the relevant tiles.

Comment: What do you think about eps? I just think something which I can then put to a publication. Eps seems to be slow.

Comment: PDF and EPS are very similar both derived from PostScript, EPS being even less efficient. They are not originally developt to display bit images, but for typesetting characters. Yes you can include an image in a PDF file, but it is non-optimized. Your publication platform will determine what is acceptable, what you use during the process up to publication is (hopefully) under your control. If you need to publish PDF, convert to it at the latest possible moment using some mark-up language for the text and PNG/TIFF images for the imagery.

Comment: For anything scientific you should seriously consider using (La)TeX, it takes some time to get up to speed, but it is worth it. I am glad I did back in 1986, one of the few skills from that time I still can directly use.

Comment: Of course, I am using LaTeX. Now, I am just doing the computation of my graphs. I am just thinking some format which is lightweight and can be integrated with LaTeX.

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157299/importing-a-png-file-into-tex-file) help? I haven't ever tried anything with more than 4k resolution in LaTeX myself, so I have no clue how/if that handles the resolutions you are talking about.